# fonts, style, color, for a thesis writing

Tags: fonts, fontsize, font-encodings, math-fonts

I am sorry to ask this as this may be difficult to know, but any idea what fonts, colour, or in general, what kind of set-up has been used to write [this thesis](http://othes.univie.ac.at/12242/1/2010-11-10_8755184.pdf)? Thank you very much.

Comment: you can use the font menu of your pdf reader or the pdffonts utility, the fonts used are the standard latex latin modern and ams fonts together with helvetica, arial and arial black sans serif and some use of times roman.

Comment: the list of fonts is ArialBlack ArialNarrow Helvetica Helvetica-Bold Helvetica-Narrow Helvetica-Narrow-Bold LMMathExtension10-Regular LMMathItalic10-Regular LMMathItalic12-Regular LMMathItalic5-Regular LMMathItalic6-Regular LMMathItalic7-Regular LMMathItalic8-Regular LMMathSymbols10-Regular LMMathSymbols5-Regular LMMathSymbols6-Regular LMMathSymbols7-Regular LMMathSymbols8-Regular LMRoman10-Bold LMRoman10-Italic LMRoman10-Regular LMRoman12-Bold LMRoman12-Italic LMRoman12-Regular LMRoman17-Regular LMRoman5-Regular ...

Comment: LMRoman6-Regular LMRoman7-Regular LMRoman8-Bold LMRoman8-Italic LMRoman8-Regular LMSans10-Bold LMSans10-Regular LMSans12-Regular LMSans8-Regular MSAM7 MSBM10 MSBM7 Times-Roman dsss12 dsss8 esint10

Comment: David Thanks, I had no idea about these.

Comment: the pdf was made with itext not tex (but given the fonts used I assume it was made with tex originally and post processed with itext)

Comment: In any case, I am not able to achieve that result in my latex. Period. :( Thanks anyway.